# GLSL weird '<' syntax error in vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Ok, so i'm starting my adventure with openGL 4 and shaders. And i occured weird syntax error while compiling vertext shader.

Even when i take simple vertex shader:

```
#version 400
in vec3 vector_position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vector_position, 1.0);
}
```

i do get this error:

> Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
>   ERROR: 0:1: error(#132) Syntax error: '<' parse error
>   ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated

What is weird about this, my fragment shader is compiling without errors:

```
#version 400
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and gives this message:

> compiler_log:
>   Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

I tried testing those shaders by putting them as const char* in code, and they work fine.

To make it easier here are some additional informations:

- using SDL 2.0
- initializing OpenGL by SDL2.0
- using GLEW to load extensions
- reading text files by this function:

  ```
  std::ifstream file(path);

  if(!file.good())
  {
      OutputDebugStringA("File not found");
      return nullptr;
  }

  std::stringstream stream ;
  stream << file.rdbuf();

  file.close();

  return stream.str();
  ```

Edit:

Adding '\0' at the end of string containing shader gave me other error:

```
compiler_log:
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:1: error(#132) Syntax error: '1.0' parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Edit2:

Someone wants to show him how do i handle whole string:

```
ShaderClass ShaderLoaderClass::createStaticShader(const std::string& file)
{
    ResourceManager manager;
    std::string container = "Just simple container";
    container = manager.loadTextFile(file + ".vs");
    container.push_back('\0');
    //OutputDebugStringA(container.c_str());
    const char* vertex_shader = container.c_str();
    GLint lenVS = container.length();
    container = manager.loadTextFile(file + ".fs");
    container.push_back('\0');
    //OutputDebugStringA(container.c_str());
    const char* fragment_shader = container.c_str(); 
    GLint lenFS = container.length();


    unsigned int vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, &lenVS);
    glCompileShader (vs);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, &lenFS);
    glCompileShader (fs);

    checkErrors(vs);
    checkErrors(fs);

    unsigned int shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
    glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

    return ShaderClass(shader_programme);
}
```

Comment: ok, but is it possible, when i do only compile each of them once?

Comment: Are you sur to pass a vec3 to your vertex shader ?

Comment: vertex shader is not even compiling due to this error

Comment: Didn't you think about encoding? Maybe you save the vertex shader in utf8 but loading it in code as ASCII? ifstream uses char by the default

Comment: I fixed this one by adding '\0' at the end of my string containing shader. And now i do have other error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your problem

```
const char* vertex_shader = container.c_str();
GLint lenVS = container.length();
container = manager.loadTextFile(file + ".fs");
```

after this the `vertex_shader` pointer is **not** valid anymore, the `c_str()` pointer is only valid *as long as the container doesn't change* (assigning to it is changing)

use 2 std::strings instead:

```
std::string vertex_container = manager.loadTextFile(file + ".vs");
//OutputDebugStringA(vertex_container.c_str());
const char* vertex_shader = vertex_container.c_str();
GLint lenVS = vertex_container.length();

std::string fragment_container = manager.loadTextFile(file + ".fs");    
//OutputDebugStringA(fragment_container.c_str());
const char* fragment_shader = fragment_container.c_str(); 
GLint lenFS = fragment_container.length();
```

Comment: +1, that's certainly _a_ problem. Though I still have my doubts on the loadTextFile function, considering the implementation does return a char *

Comment: @Bahbar `stringstream::str()` returns a `std::string` so that should be fine.

Comment: oops, there goes my quick-reading. Yup, you're right.

Comment: Ty, too much programming in java and i forgot basics in c++... + i'm dumb. Ty once more